# Ruby Rails - Where to start my understanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn code and currently running through the exercises within codecademy for Rails.

Though I find this a good learning resource, i'm struggling to understand the relevance of the commands etc to "real life", so I can relate to it.

Can anyone recommend "real life" projects to work through on line re. rails, so I can piece all the fundamental pieces together, whilst seeing what my actions do to the outcome project.

Thank you in advance.

Brendan

Comment: The best project to work through is your own. Figure out what problem you want to solve and then apply the tools to it.

Comment: Cheers for this - will put to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [www.ulearnr.com](http://www.ulearnr.com) they seem to have some good foundation tutorials on ruby on rails.

Comment: Cheers for this - will put to use.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. It focuses on stuff that matters by developing a Twitter-like app step by step. Also, it is free to read online..

https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Cheers for this - will put to use.